# Initialize a Variable Twice in the Same Line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

I've been looking at some Javascript/AngularJS code and something that stood out to me was this:

```
var searchModel = $scope.searchModel = new SearchModel('id');
```

I haven't seen that before and I haven't been able to find a good explanation online for it. I was wondering if someone could tell me exactly what's going on with this code?

Comment: It's just a shorthand way of assigning both `searchModel` and `$scope.searchModel` to the same value

Comment: It's creating a new `SearchModel` and assigning it to `$scope.searchModel` and a local variable named `searchModel`. ["Chaining the assignment operator is possible in order to assign a single value to multiple variables."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2)

Comment: Gotcha. So in this case, is it really just for convenience, i.e. so you don't have to type "$scope.searchModel" and can just type "searchModel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects are mutable , that means they are references , so when you use equal to operator , scan for left you will assign the  new SearchModel('id'); to scope variable and now that points to that objects means they are nothing but the same , now this scope variable is assigned to var variable which will again contain the same object reference.